# Checking whether e-mail address exists; or at least whether it doesn't exist

Tags: php, email

I have a C++ application that has a feedback form where the user provides their e-mail. Some people enter garbage, or just make typos. Ideally, I would like to verify the address directly in the software. Failing that, I would like to verify it in our PHP script that handles these feedback submissions.

Now, similar questions had been asked a lot on SO, and the general consensus seems to be that the only way to make sure that an address exists is to send an e-mail to it, which is obviously not the solution for me. However, there's a twist to my question making it less of a duplicate: I get it that you can't really check that an address **exists**, but can you at least check that it **doesn't exist**?

As in, I'll be happy to have a tool that will say `this address is invalid` for *some percentage* of the invalid addresses, and will have no false positives. Are there any options?

Comment: No. You can't. Every time someone tries to do that they fail. For example Facebook believes my email does not exist. I have emailed them from that mail saying it exists but they don't care. They probably have some complex pattern that they don't want to try and fix.

Comment: I could buy the domain `homail.com` and your pattern would think it's a misspelled `hotmail.com`

Comment: @Andreas: note that I'm not talking about verifying the address as a string, like a regex or whatnot. I'm not talking about whether this address complies with RFC rules and could possibly be a valid address. What I am talking about is interacting with the target server via some networking protocol to ask it whether or not it has this address.

Comment: If that would be possible, life as we know it would seize. Spammers would use this tool to find all emails at the touch of a button.

Comment: You could do an SMTP exchange, and see if the rcpt to: part of the protocol is rejected.  You could background queue this to filter out some.  Or if there's something in it for the user, email them back, and get them to click a url that you could use to confirm their address - a receipt.

Comment: A good way to check the validity of an email is to send a confirmation email with a link the user will have to click on to validate its email address.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pinging method for determining if email exists. It's a quite complex you can read about it here:

https://tools.verifyemailaddress.io/Articles/Ping/How_To_Ping_Email_Address

Also there is an api that you can use for validating email. Read about it here: https://tools.verifyemailaddress.io/

Comment: These two methods aren't absolutely sure, you can have false and true positives with each of them.

Comment: The only absolutely sure solution is sending an actual email, which is not an option in this case, so the most reliable solution is this.

Answer (score 1):

When a verification mail is not an option, there are two things you can check

General form

Validate the email address against a regular expression (http://emailregex.com)

Validate host

You can check the DNS records of the host portion. If example.com in info@example.com does not return a DNS record or when there is no valid MX host defined, the email can be considered invalid

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record